# DataGrid and ObservableCollection Biding not updating at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

**Background:**

I have a `DataGrid` that is populated with an `ObservableCollection`.
The `ObservableCollection` will not contain any item at *design-time*.

I update the collection at *run-time* with the contents of a `TextBox`, looping through a imported .Text/.CSV file and pasting the text from the clipboard.
As you will see below, I bind the collection in the XAML and specify the columns details in the `DataGrid`.

The collection is initiated with the class for the data to be displayed.

I can add the items to the `DataGrid` directly with the button click and it appears, but when I add it to the `ObservableCollection` it does not display although it is added to the collection.

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SysCheck_DataGrid" 
          BorderBrush="Gray"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_SysCheckDataGridSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
          AlternationCount="2">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hostname" Binding="{Binding Hostname}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Address" Binding="{Binding IPAddress}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Online" Binding="{Binding Online}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Restarted" Binding="{Binding LastRestarted}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="OS" Binding="{Binding OS}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code behind C#:**

```
private void SysCheck_Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text))
    {
        var item = _SysCheckDataGridSource.SingleOrDefault(
            i => i.Hostname == SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text);

        if (item == null)
        {
            SysCheck_DataGrid.Items.Add(new SystemCheckingNormal()
                { Hostname = SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text });

            SystemChecking_Log.Text += Environment.NewLine + SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text
                + " was added to DataGrid " + "There are "
                + _SysCheckDataGridSource.Count + " items in the list";

            SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            SystemChecking_Log.Text += Environment.NewLine + SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text
                + " Is already in the DataGrid " + "There are "
                + _SysCheckDataGridSource.Count + " items in the list";

            SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Code:**

```
public class SystemCheckingNormal
{
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Online { get; set; }
    public string LastRestarted { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

**Answering Questions:**

mm8 asked:

Where is your `ObservableCollection` and where and how do you add items to it?

Answer:

```
public ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal> _SysCheckDataGridSource;
```

Is in the `MainWindow` class

and:

```
_SysCheckDataGridSource = new ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal>();
```

is in the `MainWindow()` constructor.

I'm adding to the collection in the `Click` event so far (in the code above):

```
SysCheck_DataGrid.Items.Add(new SystemCheckingNormal()
    { Hostname = SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text });
```

Comment: Where is your ObservableCollection and where and how do you add items to it?

Comment: Please read about properties of `Binding` before use them. `Mode=TwoWay` doesn't make sense for `ItemsSource` binding.

Comment: @mm8 Please see my reply in the original question

Comment: @NigelTatschner: Please see my answer. _SysCheckDataGridSource is a field. It must be a property. Add the {get; set; } part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_SysCheckDataGridSource` is a *field*:

```
public ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal> _SysCheckDataGridSource;
```

You can only bind to *public properties* (but not fields) in WPF:

```
public ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal> SysCheckDataGridSource { get; set; }
```

Also note that you should remove the underscore from the property name (remember to modify this in the XAML markup as well).

You also need to set the `DataContext` of the view:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SysCheckDataGridSource = new ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal>();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've added the changes in but am still not getting anything in the DataGrid, I chnaged the ADD to this :                         SysCheckDataGridSource.Add(new SystemCheckingNormal()
                        {
                            Hostname = SysCheck_Manuel_Add_TB.Text
                        });

Comment: Do you set the DataContext of the view somewhere?

Comment: No, do I change ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SysCheckDataGridSource}" to something else?

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, i'm new to wpf and c# this is the source : https://github.com/ntatschner/NT-Tools

Comment: You're missing setting the DataContext. See my edit.

Comment: And remove this from the XAML: DataContext="{Binding Path=SysCheckDataGridSource}"

Comment: Ahh, OK, that worked!.(I now have a blank row for some reason) I'm not following MVVM atm, only found out about it after I started this project. Would you recommend restarting from scratch?

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to learn MVVM. There is a reason why it is *the* recommended design pattern to follow when building XAML based UI applications.

Answer (score 1):

your ObservableCollection Property have to be a public Property. In your case it should look like

```
public ObservableCollection<SystemCheckingNormal> _SysCheckDataGridSource {get;set;}
```

the DataContext for the DataGrid have to be an instance with this property.

Answer (score -2):

Your class need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged like this

```
public class SystemCheckingNormal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string hostname ;
    private string iPAddress ;
    private string online ;
    private string lastRestarted ;
    private string oS ;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    Public string Hostname
    {
       get{return hostname;}
       set
       {
          if(hostname != value)
            {
              hostname = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Hostname");
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Just do the same for all the other variables (i wrote only Hostname to let you understand)

Comment: This is only required if you intend to change the property values of the individual SystemCheckingNormal object dynamically at runtime. It has nothing to do with the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am intending to alter after I get this part working :) @ Daniel